# In Wasabi, whenever I try to run the start command, I get a chillax error regarding mysql. How can I fix this?

Tags: virtualbox, mysql, docker

I'm trying to run Wasabi for the first time, with either sudo or no sudo, using `./bin/wasabi start:wasabi` or `./bin/wasabi.sh build start`, on abn Ubuntu VirtualBox, the last 3 lines I get are:

```
wasabi: starting
03ccadec6659ec....
chill'ax error: not started
```

I then try `docker container ls -a` and see this:

[what I have as my containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4pQi.png)

I think I'm making a mistake with MySql, but the [documentation is thin about MySQl](https://github.com/intuit/wasabi/blob/develop/README.md).

I've tried with this about [MySQL server to get a correct container](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.5/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html), and tried what [this guy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31919317/5927871). I need to run this and not get chillax errors. I have hit `export MYSQL_HOST=localhost`. Also, I tried with MySQL server, tho the documentation for wasabi indicated it wants these to show up when using `docker container ls -a`:

```
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                     NAMES
8c12458057ef        wasabi-main              "entrypoint.sh wasabi"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090->8090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8180->8180/tcp    wasabi-main
979ecc885239        mysql:5.6                "docker-entrypoint.sh"   26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                                                    wasabi-mysql
2d33a96abdcb        cassandra:2.1            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       7000-7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9160->9160/tcp   wasabi-cassandra
```

How can I get no more chillax errors and Wasabi running? When I run `./bin/wasabi.sh start:mysql`, I get `Unknown MySQL server host '<no value>' (0)`